# out_field in ArcGIS Python API returning unwanted fields

Tags: arcgis-python-api, jupyter-notebook, arcgis-notebook

I am trying to output ONLY the `Name` Field in sdf using ArcGIS Python API and Notebook like thia

```
query = layer.query(where="POP2010 > 1000000", out_fields='NAME')
query.sdf
```

But I am getting the `FID`, and `SHAPE` too!

[image]

Why is this happening and how I can fix this to only get the `Name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is expected behaviour for an SeDF, it must have id and geometry fields and the [examples in the documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/guide/part2-data-io-reading-data/#:%7E:text=The%20query()%20method%20allows%20you%20to%20specify%20a%20number%20of%20optional%20parameters%20that%20may%20further%20refine%20and%20transform%20the%20results.%20One%20such%20key%20parameter%20is%20out_fields.%20With%20out_fields%2C%20you%20can%20subset%20your%20data%20by%20specifying%20a%20list%20of%20field%20names%20to%20return.) show this.

Just turn it into a regular pandas dataframe:

```
pd.DataFrame(sdf["NAME"])
```